How to connect to phpMyAdmin database using XAMPP and NetBeans?
I'm having trouble connecting my database from phpMyAdmin with NetBeans IDE 21. I get an error message saying:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at localhost Port 80


I am using XAMPP and php to access the database.
I tried to change the port numbers, I've checked that all the documents were in the XAMPP htdocs folder, but nothing worked.

It's unclear what you're trying to do or what you've done. "connecting my database from PHPmyAdmin with NetBeans IDE 21" makes little sense. PHPMyAdmin is simply a web based management tool for managing mysql/mariadb. Are you trying to connect to the actual database from Netbeans, or are you simpy trying to open a web page with PHPMyAdmin in Netbeans? The screenshot is just a browser with a 404 error, What exactly did you try? You left that out of your question.

https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/ide/mysql/
